# Minute Long Redstone Delay

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Currently I have something like this set up:
B-R-R-R-C-R-R-R-C-R-R-R-C (etc...)

B stands for a redstone block, R stands for a repeater, and C stands for a command block.

I have a line like this (curling back once in a while, but **not a loop**) up to a **minute** -- but this method uses 120 repeaters at full delay. What circuit could I use to create something that behaves AS CLOSE AS POSSIBLE to what I have now, but taking up less space? Specifically:

1) Removing the redstone block power source won't stop the already-sent signal
2) Must have room for gradual command blocks (so at 20 seconds I could have a command block, at 30, at 35, etc...)

For specifics, this is my Deathmatch system in a vanilla Survival Games map. When the minute is over, it reaches command blocks which teleport everyone to one location. The admin in the match uses a command button in a /tellraw command to start the countdown for Deathmatch when (s)he deems it appropriate - this command sets a redstone block as the input. After it is placed, it remains placed for the rest of the game -- but I want to be able to destroy it while not stopping the minute countdown for debugging purposes. And, as it's a countdown, it needs to be able to send out a signal every second to command blocks for stuff like "15 more seconds until Deathmatch!"

Summary: I am looking for a delay as opposed to a timer. I do not want a signal that loops and am **not looking for a necessarily long delay**, I just want an **accurate** delay that is more efficient than using repeaters AND **can support gradual output** (IE at half delay an output, at three quarters, etc...) **Hooking a timer up to an AND gate with the input won't work *as far as I know (if you know a way please tell)*** because if the timer was half-passed when the input was given, then the "delay" would be half the intended time. And removing the input signal **should NOT stop the delay from continuing.** It also needs to be **silent**, as it is close to the surface, and non-laggy (no super-quick repeater loops).

I am asking for a very specific redstone circuit, I know.

Comment: Do I get to refuke why it's not a duplicate, or let moderators decide by themselves?

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach Simply explain your thinking :) no one knows what you're looking for better than you do.

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach the solutions presented by both Fredley and myself can accommodate those requirements.  However, usually you would just set up multiple timers that are triggered simultaneously.

Comment: Ok. Well, I have reasons for why the answers to that question aren't suitable -- and that question was asked a year ago (hopefully there are better methods now). The key in my question is that I can have gradual command blocks throughout the time, where his question only has 1 destination command block.

Comment: But, as I said, unless you want to use a whole lot of repeaters, most people simply set up a separate timer for each command block.  And you can still use Fredley's solution to at least compact the redstone between command blocks using your current design.

Comment: So the answer is that I do have to use a whole lot of repeaters? Well then, that's the answer I'm looking for. :/

Comment: As for Fredley's solution: I can't use it. It works for an effectively LONG CONTINUOUS timer, but I'm looking for an ACCURATE TOGGLED timer.

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach Fredley's solution can very easily be turned into a toggled timer (i.e. monostable circuit).  Much more easily than the solution I presented.  Use some imagination.  If you don't understand how to get Fredley's solution to work for you, _ask that_!  Don't get angry at me after I've pointed you at a solution.  Ask me how to use that solution if you don't already understand it for yourself.

Comment: #MBraedley I'm not angry at anyone, I'm just frustrated that my question got misinterpretted.

Comment: @MBraedley Wow, epic fail. Clearly new to this. I'm not sure I understand about turning Fredley's into a toggled timer -- should I make a new question for this or just edit this existing one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12934/discussion-between-mbraedley-and-james-of-da-peach)

Comment: [As per chat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/snjy1o2iob0ad7s/Creative.zip).

Comment: Every timer can easily be switched, just place its output and a switch through an AND gate...

Comment: But then if the timer is half done when the input is given, it will take half the time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to fill this up with arrow from time to time, you could use an arrow that shoots into a wooden button. The arrow will activate the button and despawn after exactly 1 minute, unpressing the button again:

[image]

You could also use a bunch of `T-FlipFlops` which toggle on/off every time they get a signal. If you put them in a row, it will take much longer until the last one is toggled. (This is a binary counter)
In fact, any additional T-FlipFlop will need double the time until it's re-activated.
[image]

Comment: For the first one: I'd still need bunches of repeaters for the gradual outputs, but it's good to know the despawn time for an arrow (thx).

Comment: Since you're already using command blocks, you can have one run periodically (have it be triggered by a daylight sensor maybe) to spawn a chest full of arrows above a hopper above that dispenser.  Then you don't have to manually refill it.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the circuit you pretty much *can* plug a hopper timer into any place you have looping repeaters. It's a very versatile circuit. In this case, you've got a series of command blocks that pulse every given amount of time. If that given amount of time is constant, you can use a hopper timer set to the appropriate delay (it might take some experimentation, but I found that 7 items we pretty close to 2.5 seconds on, 2.5 seconds off).

And you can turn off this type of timer too by forcibly locking one of the hoppers, like so:

[image: Illustration of locking a hopper timer in the "off" state]

From there, (I assume this is your test world that MBraedley posted in the comments), you've got some good ideas on how to use a clock like this to drive the circuit (I honestly would not have thought of doing it that way). For the sake of people who have this type of question in the future, I'm going to go ahead and break that part down.

[image: Series of hoppers taking a continuous clock and turning it into a sequentially changing output]

Essentially, this circuit takes the clock provided by the timer of your choice (in this case, a hopper timer), and sends it sequentially down the line by locking and unlocking a series of hoppers. When the timer starts, an item is dropped into the hopper system, and the first command block triggers. This item goes down the line until it reaches the end. When it reaches the end, it resets a RS-NOR latch that locks the hopper timer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a scoreboard

```
/scoreboard objectives add timer dummy
```

Then I summon an armor stand that count the seconds,

```
/summon armor_stand x y z {PersistenceRequired:1b,CustomName:timer}
```

Then a set up a 1 second delay clock,

```
B*-R-R-D#
D*-D-R-C#
```

B* stand next to D*, then C# next to D#

Where;

B = solid, redstone-passable block,
C = command block with, `/scoreboard players remove  @e[type=armor_stand,name=timer,score_timer_min=0] timer 1`,
D = redstone dust

When actually its 15 seconds left,
Set up a Repeat, Always Active command block with:

```
/testfor @e[name=timer,type=armor_stand,score_timer_min=15,score_timer=15]
```

It connect with a Chain,(Conditional?),Always active command block with the same direction,or a comparactor then a Impulse, Need Redstone command block with:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"You have 15 seconds left!","color":"dark_red"}
```

And when the times up,
Set up a Repeat, Always Active command block with :

```
/testfor @e[name=timer,type=armor_stand,score_timer_min=0,score_timer=0]
```

And then the same procedure(Chain command block or Impulse command block) with:

```
/tp @a x y z
```

Also I suggest putting up `/spreadplayers` but I'm not sure how.

To start the timer:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[name=timer,type=armors_stand] timer 120
```

where 120 means 120 seconds.

Tested this for 1.11 Minecraft version.